# How to access a table from a has_and_belongs_to_many model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have a model that acts as a join table called CELEBRATIONS.

```
CELBERATION
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
belongs_to :board

 create_table :celebrations do |t|
      t.column :board_id,        :int, :null => false
      t.column :user_id,         :int, :null => false 
      t.column :role,            :string, :null => false 
      t.column :token,           :string
      t.timestamps
      end


USER
has_many :celebrations

Board
has_many :celebrations
```

The Roles in the CELEBRATIONS TABLE ARE: OWNER, MANAGER, OR FRIEND

I would like the USERS records for a BOARD where the role is FRIEND.

I seem to be missing something.

```
 @invited_friends = User.find(:all, :include => :celebrations, :conditions => ["board_id = ?, role = ?", @board.id, "FRIEND"])
```

could anyone point me in the right direct? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having the wrong relationship in your models.
For HABTM,

```
CELBERATION
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

USER
has_and_belongs_to_many :celebrations


And one more table celebrations_users with user_id, celebration_id columns.
Put the role column in users table.
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish. I just realized what I think I need to re-examine my relationships.